# How to set userprofile property filter in SharePoint online using CSOM keyword query

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile, keywordquery

I am running one windows task scheduler job to update all user profile properties to disable "Email notifications" using CSOM , however I am not getting any search results for SPS-EmailOptin. This is integer field, if its set to 0 then all notifications are enabled.

When I pass the wild card (*) or other filter (e.g FirstName )then its returning results.

keywordQuery.QueryText = "SPS-EmailOptin:0";
keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");

Please let us know this syntax is correct.

Comment: Is this property added as a query'able managed property?

Comment: There is no managed property for SPS-EmailOptin, I assume we need to pass property internal name

Comment: Or maybe just create one. There should be a crawled property for this user profile prop